# Navbar Burger (Dropdown) pushes content down?

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

When my navbar collapses the burger menu shows up. Whenever I click on it all the content below gets pushed down and leaves me with a messed up homepage.

My Navbar:

```
<section class="nav-bar">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="WildfireGraphic1.png" class="rounded float-left" alt="icon1"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Film</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Info</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Über uns</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</section>
```

My CSS:

```
body{
    text-align: justify !important;
}

#nav-bar{
    position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
    width: 100px;

}
.navbar-brand img{
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 30;
}

.navbar-nav li{
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.navbar-nav li a{
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav-bar ul li a:hover{
    color: #000000!important;
}

.navbar{
    background: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggler{
    border: none!important;
}

.nav-link{
    color: #555!important;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

I have tried using the Z-Index method but no luck so far. Maybe I did something wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqzs1jdw/8/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer your sample site ?

Comment: not sure what you mean but I added jsfiddle.

Comment: Just a typo, change `#` too `.` on your nav-bar element in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You have just make a typo, change the `#` to `.` will fix the issue

**Example:**

```
.nav-bar{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aslamb/sfoavupd/2/

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer and up vote if it's helpful